# Eclipse Exclude/Include

Tags: eclipse, vaadin

I'm new to eclipse. I was having a problem with one of my classes so instead of commenting the whole thing out, I right-clicked and clicked exclude. Now I don't know how to bring it back into the project. Wouldn't it make sense for there to be an "include" button right next to exclude? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see everything that is excluded, examine the whole build path in the UI with Project Properties' Build Path.

To access, Right-click on project, Choose `Properties` and select `Java Build Path`. You can now browse and remove any exclusions you no longer desire.

See this screenshot if it helps.

[image]

Comment: You rock. Thanks a mill.